# Kubectl command with jenkins pipeline and eks

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, plugins, cicd

i am trying to do CD using jenkins over EKS.

I used container called kubectl that integrated with kubernetes plugin and deployed as pod to be able to use kubectl command and deploy my manifest thorugh my pipeline. here is the yaml file

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
  namespace: jenkins-ns
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - /busybox/cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: docker-config
      mountPath: /kaniko/.docker
  
  - name: kubectl
    image: bitnami/kubectl:1.28.2
    command:
      - "/bin/sh"
      - "-c"
      - "sleep 99d"
    tty: true
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0 #if isn't set, it will cause in logic error
  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: docker-config
    projected:
      sources:
      - secret:
          name: my-registery-key
          items:
          - key: .dockerconfigjson
            path: config.json
```

I sat up credentails with type File that contain my ./kube/config and copied it inside the pod give it ability to communicate with the cluster and configured specific stage to use that container

```
stage('Deploy on EKS') {
            steps {
                container (name:'kubectl', shell: '/bin/sh' ) {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'KUBECONFIGFILE', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {
                    sh '''
                        echo $KUBECONFIG > /.kube/config &&
                        apt-get update &&
                        apt-get install -y awscli &&  
                        aws eks --region eu-west-1 update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster &&
                        
                        aws --version &&

                        kubectl config view
                    '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However i wasn't able to deploy or connect to the eks. It seems /.kube/config retrieved with missed info that indicate the file wrongly copied or something https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AfIJ.png.

after some debugging, I managed to cat ./kube/config that exist inside the container and it was identical with the original one and there is no **indentation error** or missing **:**

here is my full pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'kaniko-kubectl.yaml'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        // stage('Build & Push Docker Image') {
        //     steps {
        //         container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh'){
        //             sh '''
        //                 /kaniko/executor --dockerfile `pwd`/Dockerfile --context `pwd` --destination=omarsater/private-repo:python-v1.1
        //             '''
        //         }
        //     }
        // }

       
        stage('Deploy on EKS') {
            steps {
                container (name:'kubectl', shell: '/bin/sh' ) {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'KUBECONFIGFILE', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {
                    sh '''
                        echo $KUBECONFIG > /.kube/config &&
                        apt-get update &&
                        apt-get install -y awscli &&  
                        aws eks --region eu-west-1 update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster &&
                        
                        aws --version &&

                        kubectl config view
                    '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I can't totally tell what this setup is trying to do: it seems like you're creating a bare Pod (usually discouraged), with two containers (usually you'd prefer just one), neither of which actually does anything.  Can you arrange for `kubectl` to be directly available in your Jenkins setup instead?  How would Jenkins manage to connect to that Pod if it doesn't already have access to Kubernetes?

Comment: First i want to build and push image without manullay involved my worker node in docker daemon stuff. So I used Kainko solution integrated with kubernetes plugin. 
Second. the same reason I used Kainko for (which is moving around the hustle of setup necessary softwares and packages on worker node such as docker daemon). I used another container to give me ability to use kubectl commands, And both pods is created to do certain jobs and died. 
I hope I explained in a good way. Thanks

Comment: #1 The error image says : yaml line 31 ....  . Did you check that line?  #2 How is your jenkins installed? #3 Enter to the jenkins shell and perform the k8 commands and share us the result #4 Try with a "pure" jenkins or a hello world yaml, nothing complicated just to validate.